# How to set the width of the fixed columns in xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a ListView that shows chemical residues, the problem is that when I add a particular residue ("BORRAS") my column configuration goes to shit as shown in the following figure

[image: ListView]

I think there is a nomenclature to set the width of the columns, how can I solve this? How can I make my ListView look homogenous?

I attach my ListView.XAML:

```
<ListView
    SelectionMode="None"
    Margin="5,0,10,10"
    IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}"
    HeightRequest="{Binding AltoListaResiduos}"
    SeparatorVisibility="None"  
    HasUnevenRows="true"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ListaResiduos}">

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                             VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <!--NOMBRE RESIDUO-->
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                            <!--CANTIDAD ESTIMADA-->
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5*"/>
                            <!--NOMBRE ESTIMADA-->
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5*"/>
                            <!--CANTIDAD CONTENEDOR-->
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5*"/>
                            <!--NOMBRE CONTENEDOR-->
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Label Text="{Binding NombreResiduo}"
                               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"                                                      
                               MaxLines="3"
                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                               TextColor="{StaticResource das.color.texto}"
                               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               Margin="4,0">
                            <Label.FontSize>
                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="11" Android="11" />
                            </Label.FontSize>
                        </Label>
                        <Label Text="{Binding formattedCantidadEstimada}" 
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                               FontSize="Small" 
                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                               TextColor="{StaticResource das.color.texto}"
                               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Margin="4,0">
                        </Label>

                        <Label Text="{Binding Estimado}" 
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                               FontSize="Micro" 
                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                               TextColor="{StaticResource das.color.texto}"
                               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                               Grid.Column="2"
                               Margin="4,0">
                        </Label>

                        <Label Text="{Binding CantidadContenedor}" 
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="End" 
                               FontSize="Small" 
                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                               TextColor="{StaticResource das.color.texto}"
                               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                               Grid.Column="3"
                               Margin="4,0">
                        </Label>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Contenedor}" 
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                               FontSize="Micro" 
                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                               TextColor="{StaticResource das.color.texto}"
                               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                               Grid.Column="4"
                               Margin="4,0">
                        </Label>

                    </Grid>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I'm new to Xamarin.Forms and I hope this question helps others, how can I make my list look the same with all the waste? (independent of the name) any help for me?

Comment: You shouldn't need the `StackLayout` at all since you are defining a `Grid` with the appropriate columns.

Comment: Do you have the correct answer, do you want to write it to mark it as correct? @TaylorD

Comment: Check my answer below for the correct understanding of the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need the `StackLayout` at all since you are defining a `Grid` with the appropriate columns.

This should help your **Grid** to span properly and fill the entire space

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling this is happening because you are using `VerticalTextAlignment` now for some reason both the TextAlignment Properties(H, V) have weird behaviors in them, even though Xamarin says for `VerticalTextAlignment` that it

> Gets or sets the vertical alignment of the Text property.

I would rather use `YAlign` instead as it does not have this behavior and Xamarin says about YAling that it

> Gets or sets the vertical alignment for the Text inside of the Label bound.

Secondly, when you use a grid layout a define the columns and rows you should never use `AndExpand` types as you have already defined the max area and it will not overlay that. Now what the [LayoutOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.layoutoptions?view=xamarin-forms) docs say is `CenterAndExpand` or FillAndExpand do is

> A LayoutOptions structure that describes an element that is centered and expands.

Also, Remove the `StackLayout` just keep the `Grid` in your ViewCell.

```
   <Label Text="{Binding Contenedor}" 
                           XAlign="End"
                           FontSize="Micro" 
                           YAlign="Center"
                           TextColor="{StaticResource das.color.texto}"                               
                           Grid.Column="4"
                           Margin="4,0"/>
```

Want to learn the best practices with Xamarin forms? Check my blog here: https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/techniques-for-improving-performance-in-a-xamarin-forms-application-b439f2f04156